# Howto get suid and sgid bit of files and directories with PHP?

Tags: php, file-permissions, chmod

PHP `chmod` is able to set the suid/sgid bit of files, i.e. `chmod('my-directory', 04775)` just works fine.

However, I am unable to check if the suid/sgid bit is set with `fileperms`, the fourth octal digit (from the right) will always be reported as zero, i.e. `fileperms('my-directory') & 07000 == 0` always holds.

The docs clearly states

> The value of mode contains information read by several functions. When written in octal, starting from the right, the first three digits are returned by chmod(). **The next digit is ignored by PHP.** The next two digits indicate the file type: [...]

(see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php)

Is there any option how I can check with PHP whether suid/sgid are set?

It seems a bit inconsistent that one can set the suid/sgid bit, but cannot read it.

Comment: What is the result of `fileperms('my-directory');` and what is the output of `ls -ld my-directory` executed in your console? According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php#example-2193 it should work.